# Two dimensional matrix in Perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

Newbie's question: What does `$matrix[$row][4]=1;` mean in a code? The row and column are known to me. Why is it made equal to 1?

Comment: It is impossible to know why `1` with the information you provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command will set the *cell* at position `$row`,`4` with the value `1`

Answer (score 0):

`=` is the *assignment* operator in Perl. It assigns the value 1 to the cell at the coordinates `$row, 4`.

The *comparison* operators for equiality are `eq` for strings and `==` for numbers.